# HP 300GB SAS 2.5" Dual Port HDD

Tags: hp, sas

I have been offered a couple of HP 300Gb DUAL Port 2.5" SAS drives

will this work in a NON HP system ?

My system uses a Adaptec 6405e SAS RAID Controller
there is NO mention of DUAL port

I'm not sure what Dual Port is 
will the drives work (I don't want to damage my system !)

Answer (score 0):

The disks will work fine in a non-HP server.

They're just Seagate disks. The dual-port makes no difference for internal server use. They are compatible with single-port backplanes and cables.